# Use findstr to Search keyword in the multiple sub directories

Tags: windows, findstr

I'm looking for to find the string `"please enter your datbase connection details"` hidden inside the one of the `.php` files at a location of `C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\e-pay\script\vendor`

Inside `vendor/` there are multiple sub directories, So my task is to find the string inside this location.

**Note: Each folder has further sub directories**
[image: So, my task is to find that particular string]

**String to find:**

[image: here]

**What I tried:**

```
findstr /spin C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\e-pay\script\vendor:"please enter your datbase connection details" *.php
```

But Nothing showed up! can any body guide me the correct way how the string can be find in a particular location?

Comment: This does not relate to PHP at all, but is an OS specific question. I will remove the tag.

Comment: Whilst you might be able to get an answer on this site, I think your chances are better over at Superuser on the Stackoverflow network.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
findstr /SPIN "the string to search for" C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\e-pay\script\vendor\*.php
```

Comment: What about the inner sub directory search? ex:inside vender/abc_folder/?

Comment: The `/S` says search all sub folders of the one you mention as the start folder